# mup setup fails with "endpoint with name mongodb already exists in network bridge"

Tags: docker, meteor, meteor-up

I get an error while using mup setup:

`Error response from daemon: endpoint with name mongodb already exists in network bridge`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason was that I manually removed a previous mongodb container, without cleaning up the network.

I finally succeeded with:

`docker network disconnect bridge -f mongodb`

After this `mup setup` worked as expected.